# My Python 2.7 code has a syntax error in it. I need assistance with it

Tags: python-2.7

It gives me this syntax error whenever I run it:

```
File "main.py", line 27
decide_winner (user_choice, computer_choice) 
^
IntendationError: unexpected indent
```

I have no clue how to solve this problem, I have been working on it for about two days now and I really an experts help on this.

```
from random import randint
options = ['ROCK','PAPER','SCISSORS']
message = {"tie': 'you've tied",
          "won': 'you've won!",
          "lost': 'you've lost!"
          }
def decide_winner(user_choice, computer_choice):
  print 'you chose %s' % user_choice
  print 'computer chose %s' % computer_choice
  if user_choice == computer_choice:
    print message['tie']
  elif user_choice == options[0] and computer_choice == options[2]:
    print message['won']
  elif user_choice == options[1] and computer_choice == options[0]:
    print message['won']
  elif user_choice == options[2] and computer_choice == options[1]:
    print message['won']
  else:
    print message['lost']
def play_RPS():
  user_choice = raw_input('Enter ROCK PAPER or SCISSORS')
  user_choice = user_choice.upper()
  computer_choice = options[randint(0,2)]
    decide_winner(user_choice, computer_choice)         
play_RPS()
```